# Delphi Indy10 required SSL libraries under Linux?

Tags: delphi, cross-compiling, indy10

Using Delphy 10.4:
I am trying to start a IdTCPServer with  IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.
Under Linux, I get a "EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary; Could not load SSL library."
Under Windows, this works fine.

In the SSL directory, I now have both the Windows DLL's, and the .so files which I generated by compiling the "openssl-1.1.1j" .

So the SSL directory contains libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, libcrypto.so, libssl.so.

Why does it not accept it under Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can't use Windows DLLs on Linux.  You need Linux binaries, and on Linux  `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` will be looking for `libssl.so.x.x.x[l]` and `libcrypto.so.x.x.x[l]` (where `x.x.x` is the version `1.0.2` or lower, and `[l]` is an optional letter `a..z`, or `libssl.so`/`libcrypto.so` symlinks that map to such versions).

Second, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, and by extension `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`, [does not support OpenSSL 1.1.x](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183), only OpenSSL 1.0.2 and earlier, as you can see above.

To use OpenSSL 1.1.x, you need to use a different `IOHandler`. One is currently in a pull request awaiting review, and so has not been merged into Indy's main code yet, but you can try it and see if it works for you:

[#299 Added new OpenSSL IO Handler for OpenSSL 1.1.1](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299)

Comment: It was indeed a to-high SSL version. I have decided to install 1.0.2, as I have already to many problems to experiment with a brand-new SSL system.  It now works fine.  Thanks Remy.